# RecyclerView with Glide causing NullPointer after scrolling up again

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

Here is my Adapter class:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_accommodation,parent,false);
        MyHolder holder = new MyHolder(view);
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
        return holder;
    }

 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;
        Accommodation current = data.get(position);
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://10.0.2.2:18180/AAFS/Accommodations/"+current.AccommoID+"/Accomm_Images/"+current.AccommoMainImage.ImageName)
               .error(R.drawable.error)
                .into(myHolder.imageView);

    }
```

Here is the error I get when I try to **scroll up** again, scrolling down works fine.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                 at
>   com.example.phuluso.aafs.AdapterAccommodation.onBindViewHolder(AdapterAccommodation.java:73)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5471)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5504)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4741)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1180)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1031)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:4061)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
>                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
>                                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:524)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
>                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Paste full code of your adapter class.

Comment: Post your full adapter code. The error log is not sufficient

Comment: Added the full code below

Comment: Which is Line 73 in AdapterAccommodation.java file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you override the getItemCount method in your adapter?

```
@Override
public int getItemCount(){
    return data.size();
}
```

It seems like the `onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position)` method is supplying an invalid position parameter.  So when you get the Accommodation from your data collection it returns null.  What type of collection are you using to hold the Accommodations?

Comment: Accommodation as a type

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AdapterAccommodation extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Accommodation> data = Collections.emptyList();
    List<Accommodation> mStringFilterList;
    ValueFilter valueFilter;


    public AdapterAccommodation(Context context,List<Accommodation>data)
    {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
        mStringFilterList = data;

       }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_accommodation,parent,false);
        MyHolder holder = new MyHolder(view);
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder,  int position) {

        MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;

        Accommodation current = data.get(position);

        myHolder.textAccommoName.setText(current.AccommoName);
        myHolder.txtAddress.setText("Address: " + current.AccommoAddress.Street + ", " + current.AccommoAddress.Town + ", " + current.AccommoAddress.City);
        myHolder.txtGenderAllowed.setText("Gender Accommodated: " + current.AccommoDetails.GenderAllowed );
        myHolder.txtDistance.setText("Distance from nearest Campus: " + current.Distance + " km");
        myHolder.textCapacity.setText("Capacity: " + current.Capacity);
        myHolder.textNearestCampus.setText("Nearest Campus: "+ current.NearestCampus);


       Picasso.with(context).load("http://192.168.42.197:18180/AAFS/Accommodations/"+current.AccommoID+"/Accomm_Images/"+current.AccommoMainImage.ImageName)
               .error(R.drawable.error)
                .into(myHolder.imageView);

        myHolder.ratingBar.setRating(current.avgAccommoRating);
        myHolder.ratingBar.setIsIndicator(true);

        myHolder.btnAdditionalDetails.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context,AccommodationAdditionalDetails.class);

                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_AccommodationID",data.get(position).AccommoID);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_AccommodationName",data.get(position).AccommoName);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_AccommodationCapacity",data.get(position).Capacity);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_AccommodationNearestCampus",data.get(position).NearestCampus);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_AccommodationDistance",data.get(position).Distance);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_AccommodationAccreditedStatus",data.get(position).AccredStatus);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_AccommodationCity",data.get(position).AccommoAddress.City);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_AccommodationPostalAddress",data.get(position).AccommoAddress.PostalCode);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_LATITUDE",data.get(position).AccommoAddress.Lattitude);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_LONGITUDE",data.get(position).AccommoAddress.Longitude);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_NUM_SHARING",data.get( position ).AccommoDetails.NumTwoSharingRooms);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_NUM_SINGLE",data.get(position).AccommoDetails.NumSingleRooms);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_RENT_SINGLE",data.get(position).AccommoDetails.RentSingle);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_RENT_SHARING",data.get(position).AccommoDetails.RentSharing);

                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_WIFI",data.get(position).AccommoDetails.WiFi);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_LIBRARY",data.get(position).AccommoDetails.DedicatedStudyArea);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_GYM",data.get(position).AccommoDetails.Gym);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SECURITY_LEVEL",data.get(position).AccommoDetails.SecurityLevel);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_PARKING_LOT",data.get(position).AccommoDetails.ParkingPort);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_GENDER",data.get(position).AccommoDetails.GenderAllowed);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_TRANSPORT",data.get(position).AccommoDetails.TransportShuttle);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_WASHING_MACHINE",data.get(position).AccommoDetails.WashingMachine);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_NUM_BATHROOM",data.get( position ).AccommoDetails.NumBathrooms);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_CLEANING_SERVICE",data.get( position ).AccommoDetails.CleaningService);

                context.startActivity(intent);

                SharedPreferences settings = enter code herePreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("ACCOMMO_LATITUDE",data.get(position).AccommoAddress.Lattitude );
                editor.commit();

                SharedPreferences setting1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("ACCOMMO_LONGITUDE",data.get(position).AccommoAddress.Longitude );
                editor.commit();


            }
        } );
    }

    @Override

    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView textAccommoName;
       // ImageView ivAccommodation;
        TextView textCapacity;
        TextView textNearestCampus;
        TextView txtAddress;
        TextView txtGenderAllowed;
        TextView txtDistance;
        Button btnAdditionalDetails;
        RatingBar ratingBar;
        ImageView imageView ;
        public MyHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textAccommoName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textAccommodationName);
            txtAddress = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAddress );
            txtGenderAllowed = (TextView)itemView.findViewById( R.id.txtGenderAllowed );
            txtDistance = (TextView)itemView.findViewById( R.id.textDistanceFromNearestCampus );
            imageView = (ImageView)itemView. findViewById(R.id.imageview);
           // ivAccommodation = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            textCapacity = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textCapacity);
            textNearestCampus = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textNearestCampus);
            btnAdditionalDetails = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdditionalDetails);
            ratingBar = (RatingBar)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (valueFilter == null) {
            valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
        }
        return valueFilter;
    }


    private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<Accommodation> filterList = new ArrayList<Accommodation>();
                for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++) {
                    if ( (mStringFilterList.get(i).AccommoName.toUpperCase() )
                            .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {

                        Accommodation accommodation = new Accommodation();
                        accommodation.AccommoName = mStringFilterList.get(i).AccommoName;
                        accommodation.AccommoDetails.GenderAllowed  = mStringFilterList.get(i).AccommoDetails.GenderAllowed;
                        accommodation.AccommoAddress.Town  = mStringFilterList.get(i).AccommoAddress.Town;
                        accommodation.AccommoAddress.City =  mStringFilterList.get(i).AccommoAddress.City;
                        accommodation.Capacity =  mStringFilterList.get(i).Capacity;
                        accommodation.Distance =  mStringFilterList.get(i).Distance;
                        accommodation.AccommoAddress.Street   =  mStringFilterList.get(i).AccommoAddress.Street;
                        accommodation.NearestCampus =  mStringFilterList.get(i).NearestCampus;
                        accommodation.avgAccommoRating = mStringFilterList.get(i).avgAccommoRating;

                        filterList.add(accommodation);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            } else {
                results.count = mStringFilterList.size();
                results.values = mStringFilterList;
            }
            return results;

        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            data = (ArrayList<Accommodation>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so now that I see your adapter code I think the problem most likely lies with your filter implementation.  Try changing your `publishResults` method to:

```
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                  FilterResults results) {
    if(results.count > 0){
        data.clear();
        data.addAll(results.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }else{
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }
}
```

*Edited - The NPE occurred while trying to access the AccommoMainImage property on one of the Accommodation objects.*

Added a null check to solve the problem:

```
if(current.AccommoMainImage != null){
    Picasso.with(context).load("http://10.0.2.2:18180/AAFS/Accom‌​modations/"+current.‌​AccommoID+"/Accomm_I‌​mages/"+current.Acco‌​mmoMainImage.ImageNa‌​me) .error(R.drawable.error) .into(myHolder.imageView);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so the current Accommodation is null.  I think your underlying Accommodation collection (data) is getting messed up by either the `publishResults` method or the `permformFiltering` method of your filter class.  Did you apply the changes to the `publishResults` method?

Comment: Either that, or one of the Accommodation objects has a null AccommoMainImage property and you should add a check for null:
`if(current.AccommoMainImage != null){ Picasso.with(context).load("http://10.0.2.2:18180/AAFS/Accommodations/"+current.AccommoID+"/Accomm_Images/"+current.AccommoMainImage.ImageName)
               .error(R.drawable.error)
                .into(myHolder.imageView);}`

Comment: Thanks thats correct my last AccommoMainImage in the list is null couldn't see that. It worked thanks a lot

Comment: No prob man, please give my answer an up vote when you get a chance

Comment: Definitely. How do i do that?

Comment: Hit the up arrow to the upper left side of the answer